# css column alignment for unequal height divs

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I am trying to recreate alignment of divs with unequal heights.
Here is the JSFiddle link: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/984jgkvL/)

As per the example give if only 1 child exists it should be centered, otherwise the children should be side by side in 2 columns. I achieved that using flex but I'm facing an issue that if the height of children is big it is leaving a big space as shown in fiddle with div "weird space above this box"

SCSS code:

```
body {
  background: grey;  
}
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: white;
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;

    >li {
      border: 2px solid black;
      width: 42%;
      height: fit-content;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="parent">
    <li>child 1 </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <ul class="parent">
    <li>child 1 </li>
    <li>child 2 child 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <ul class="parent">
    <li>child 1 </li>
    <li>child 2 child 2</li>
    <li>child child child child child child child child v child child child child child child child child child child child child child child </li>
    <li>child child</li>
    <li>child child</li>
    <li>weird space above this box</li>
    <li>child child</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D I have provided a fiddle link with the code. It's not invalid it's a working fiddle link I created not some example link from the website I'm working on.

Comment: A fiddle is not acceptable. Code MUST be in the question, not a separate link. If JSF goes down (which it does often) your link is of no use,

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is the two columns to be equal height? Remove `height: fit-content;` from the `> li` css block and the heights should grow to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove height property from child. This will result in both the child taking full height.

> height: fit-content;